# MySQL Sum of Column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to get a Sum of row values, where some of the rows are different names. I know I would need to use a sum, but unsure how to do it to sum up only where row names match.

Here is the query I am currently using

```
SELECT b.visits, b.country FROM urls_analytics AS a 
JOIN analytics AS b ON a.urls_slug = b.slug 
WHERE creator_user_id='some user id'
AND a.urls_slug='some slug' 
AND b.continent="NA"
AND b.visit_date >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This is the output of my query now.

```
visits country
5      Canada
10      Canada
15      Canada
5      Canada
5      United States
10      United States
5      Austraillia
```

This is how I would like the query to return results

```
visits country
35     Canada
15      United States
5      Austraillia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) clause to do aggregation over the `country` field, and the [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function to sum the values:

```
SELECT SUM(b.visits) AS visits, b.country FROM urls_analytics AS a 
JOIN analytics AS b ON a.urls_slug = b.slug 
WHERE creator_user_id='some user id'
AND a.urls_slug='some slug' 
AND b.continent="NA"
AND b.visit_date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY b.country
```

Note that you can use `CURDATE()` as shorthand for `DATE(NOW())`

Comment: Thank you for your response, well explained.

I noticed you replaced my DATE(NOW()) by CURDATE(). Is there any performance impact from the way I did it? Or is it just convention?

Comment: @EricE it's just shorthand. The query optimiser ought to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) country names

```
SELECT sum(b.visits) sum_visits, b.country FROM urls_analytics AS a 
JOIN analytics AS b ON a.urls_slug = b.slug 
WHERE creator_user_id='some user id'
AND a.urls_slug='some slug' 
AND b.continent="NA"
AND b.visit_date >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
group by b.country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "[group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)".

```
SELECT 
    SUM(b.visits),
    b.country
FROM 
    urls_analytics AS a JOIN analytics AS b ON a.urls_slug = b.slug 
WHERE 
    creator_user_id='some user id' AND 
    a.urls_slug='some slug' AND
    b.continent="NA" AND 
    b.visit_date >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY b.country
```